# What value of theta we need to take after the substitution

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Suppose we have the def integral of $\frac{1}{√[(x-a)(b-x)] }dx$ from $a$ to $b$ , where $b>a$ , there is a special substitution which can be elegant only for def integral of $1/√$(quadratic having real  roots) that is $x = asin^2\theta + bcos^2\theta$ , but when we now change the limits , what should be those $\theta s$ we will take, I mean as for lower one will it be $\pi/2$ or $3\pi/2$ .. which one and similarily for above will it be $0$ or $\pi$ or $2\pi$ ..etc ?

[ I know one thing that for other types of problems where we substitute something the substituted thing from the integrand must be bijective , but here what we r substituting does the substituing thing too need to bijective , as "x" itself is bijective which i dont have problem]. For substituent thing i dont know what conditions should be imposed in that .

Comment: Sorry but me eyes get hurt while reading your nice question. Plz use Latex and rewrite it.

Comment: Sir/Mam extremely sry i dont know latex thats why i asked as this way , otherwise i could have latexified it for u :) , maybe someone can help in editing it

Comment: When $x=a$, you get $a=a\sin^2\theta+b\cos^2\theta$, so you want $\sin^2\theta=1$ and $\cos^2\theta=0$. That should help pin down the lower limit of integration, and there's a similar line of reasoning for the upper limit.

Comment: Sir thats the whole point i am asking of which theta we should take there r many such theta for x= a one , pi/2, 3pi/2.....

Comment: Which satsfy both sin^2theta =1 and cos^2theta = 0

Comment: Well, it probably doesn't matter which choice you make, so long as your lower limit is smaller than your upper limit, and the substitution is bijective. You can always try a few different ones (satisfying the two conditions I've given) to see whether they give the same answer (and if they don't then you have another question to ponder).

Comment: Sir thats the whole point , how can we ensure that the substitution x= asin^2theta + bcos^2theta is bijective ?

Comment: @mikasa Sir/Mam now i guess edit is all gud , u can also share ur inputs :)

Comment: If it's monotone increasing over the range of values of $\theta$, then it will be a bijection.

Comment: Yup Sir , but how will be able to deduce that asin^2theta + bcos^2theta is bijective ( i mean how to we put conditions on theta values it can take)

Comment: You pick a range of values of $\theta$. If $x$ is monotone increasing over that range of values of $\theta$, then you have a bijection. If $x$ is not monotone increasing over that range, you pick a different range of values of $\theta$, and you try again. Eventually, you figure out how to choose a range for $\theta$ that guarantees $x$ will be monotone increasing, so you will have a bijection. Try it! By the way, if you want to be sure I see a comment intended for me, you have to put @Gerry in it.

Comment: @gerry Sir i got.your pt , can u share the full method as a answer to my question i will upvote it , thats the only doubt i was having

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is, if we are dealing with $\int_a^bf(x)\,dx$, and we find it useful to make the substitution $x=a\sin^2\theta+b\cos^2\theta$ to get $\int_?^?g(\theta)\,d\theta$, then what should the new limits of integration be?

We need a value of $\theta$, call it $\theta_1$, that leads to $x=a$, and a value of $\theta$, call it $\theta_2$, that leads to $x=b$; we need $\theta_1<\theta_2$; and we need $x$ to take on every value between $a$ and $b$ exactly once as $\theta$ goes from $\theta_1$ to $\theta_2$.

To get $x=a$, we need $\sin^2\theta_1=1$ and $\cos^2\theta_1=0$. This will happen precisely when $\theta_1$ is an odd multiple of $\pi/2$. [That is, when $\theta_1=k\pi/2$ for some odd integer $k$.]

To get $x=b$, we need $\sin^2\theta_2=0$ and $\cos^2\theta_2=1$. This will happen precisely when $\theta_2$ is a multiple of $\pi$.

That leaves us with many options. E.g., we might try $\theta_1=\pi/2,\theta_2=2\pi$. But this doesn't work, since we get $x=b$ twice, at $\theta=\pi$ and again at $\theta=2\pi$. So we see we have to make our interval of $\theta$-values short, so as to get $x=a$ and $x=b$ only once each.

So, let's try $\theta_1=\pi/2$, $\theta_2=\pi$. Now we get $x=a$ exactly once, and $x=b$ exactly once. But how do we know we get every $x$ between $a$ and $b$ exactly once, and that we never get $x<a$ or $x>b$?

One way to do this is to rewrite $$x=a\sin^2\theta+b\cos^2\theta=a(1-\cos^2\theta)+b\cos^2\theta=a+(b-a)\cos^2\theta$$ Now, we know that $\cos^2\theta$ is continuous and monotone increasing from zero to one as $\theta$ goes from $\pi/2$ to $\pi$, so $x=a+(b-a)\cos^2\theta$ will be continuous and monotone increasing from $a$ to $b$ over that same range of values of $\theta$, and thus will take on every value in that interval exactly once. We're done.